# Connect USB stick using fdroid

Tags: usb, f-droid

I know there is stickmount on PlayStore to connect a USb stick to android, but is there an alternative on fdroid?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need it specifically from f-droid but you can get it from other stores like aptoide, chainfire (the author) is currently temporary retired from developing, so dont worry about missing a new update for now.